# Setting the JRE of java eclipse project in plugin programmatically

Tags: eclipse, plugins, java

I Am trying to create eclipse projects programmatically for my plugin. I used this code to create the projects:

```
IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject project = workspaceRoot.getProject(projectName);
    project.create(null);
    project.open(null);

    IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
    description.setNatureIds(new String[] { JavaCore.NATURE_ID });
    project.setDescription(description, null);

    IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project); 

    IFolder binFolder = project.getFolder("bin");
    binFolder.create(false, true, null);
    javaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(), null);

    List<IClasspathEntry> entries = new ArrayList<IClasspathEntry>();

    IVMInstall vmInstall = JavaRuntime.getDefaultVMInstall();
    LibraryLocation[] locations = JavaRuntime.getLibraryLocations(vmInstall);
    for (LibraryLocation element : locations) {
        entries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(element.getSystemLibraryPath(), null, null));
    }

    javaProject.setRawClasspath(entries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[entries.size()]), null);

    IFolder sourceFolder = project.getFolder("src");
    sourceFolder.create(false, true, null);

    IPackageFragmentRoot packageRoot = javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(sourceFolder);
    IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
    IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);
    newEntries[oldEntries.length] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(packageRoot.getPath());
    javaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null);
```

But as it runs in an eclipse application the JRE system library is not set.

So how do you add the JRE programmatically to an project in an eclipse application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreferenceConstants.getDefaultJRELibrary();

The default JRE of an Eclipse is stored in the preferences, so the call above should provide you with the Java Runtime Environment Library.

From a more extensive source with great info on creating a Project programmatically: 
http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/11/18/extending-eclipse-creating-a-java-project-without-displaying-a-wizard.html

Answer (score 3):

```
entries.add(JavaRuntime.getDefaultJREContainerEntry());
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this gives an class cast exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.ClasspathEntry cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry

Comment: In `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime` the method definition is `public static org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry getDefaultJREContainerEntry()` :|

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

```
IPath containerPath = new Path(JavaRuntime.JRE_CONTAINER);              
IVMInstall vmInstall = JavaRuntime.getDefaultVMInstall();
IPath vmPath = containerPath
    .append(vmInstall.getVMInstallType().getId())
    .append(vmInstall.getName());
IClasspathEntry jreEntry = JavaCore.newContainerEntry(vmPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            IClasspathEntry[] jreClasspaths=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PreferenceConstants.getDefaultJRELibrary();

        IClasspathEntry[] oldClasspathEntries=null;
        try{
            oldClasspathEntries=javaProject.getRawClasspath();
        }catch(JavaModelException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Set<IClasspathEntry> newClasspathEntries=new HashSet<IClasspathEntry>();
        newClasspathEntries.addAll(Arrays.asList(jreClasspaths));
        newClasspathEntries.addAll(Arrays.asList(oldClasspathEntries));
        try{
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(newClasspathEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[newClasspathEntries.size()]), monitor);
        }catch(JavaModelException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```